# Unable to set focus in new tab in Chrome browser in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read object on a new tab but driver focus is not shifting on that. Here is a scenario:
1. Open Gmail.
2. Click on "term" link below Gmail site. New Tab will get open.
3. Read any object from new tab of term link.

Unable to do step 3. Here is code

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://gmail.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    String Mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

    boolean Term = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='footer-list']/li[3]/a")).isDisplayed();
    if(Term){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='footer-list']/li[3]/a")).click();
    }
    else{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/footer/div/div[5]/div[1]/a[4]")).click(); 
        // this is written for IE and Mozila
    }

    Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(set.size());

    Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();   
    String main =it.next();
    String maintab =it.next();
    System.out.println(maintab);



    driver.switchTo().window(maintab);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maia-nav-y']/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='maia-nav-y']/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='maia-nav-y']/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);

    driver.switchTo().window(main);


        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array List instead of Set. As Set stores the elements by using a mechanism called hashing. So String 'main' or 'mainTab' may not have right window handle to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver is successfully able to switch to the new tab. However, you are trying to invoke  **sendKeys** API on a control which is not an **input** element.

If you just want to scroll page down and up in the new tab, you can do that using **JavascriptExecutor**, as shown in the below code:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.sleep(2000);

String Mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();



boolean Term = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='footer-list']/li[3]/a")).isDisplayed();
    if(Term){
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='footer-list']/li[3]/a")).click();
    }
    else{
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/footer/div/div[5]/div[1]/a[4]")).click(); 
                // this is written for IE and Mozila
}

Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(set.size());

Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();   
String main =it.next();
String maintab =it.next();
System.out.println(maintab);



driver.switchTo().window(maintab);
Thread.sleep(10000);

//Using JavaScriptExecutor
//Scroll page down
JavascriptExecutor jscriptExec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jscriptExec.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

//Scroll page up
jscriptExec.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)", "");



//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maia-nav-y']/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
//Thread.sleep(3000);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='maia-nav-y']/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP);
//Thread.sleep(3000);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='maia-nav-y']/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);

driver.switchTo().window(main);

driver.quit();
```

Comment: Will it matters?.. I need to call Keyboard method on his page which can only be called by SendKeys API

Comment: As, there is no `input` element on the second tab, `sendKeys` will throw error. However, if you just want to scroll page up and down, I have shown one of the way to achieve that in my updated answer. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Which browser U used for this code.

Comment: I had used Chrome browser and tested this code. It worked for me.

Comment: The code I shared is working for you? Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Ya its worked .I downgrade by Mozila version the it worked

Comment: Great, thanks. It will help if you accept / upvote my answer, if it has resolved or helped you in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to try this:

```
 driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```